# Encode strange characters which are unable to be sent to API Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-rpc

my name is Juraj Čarnogurský. Notice the `Č` character.
I want to send my name from the one server to API. But my last name gets replaced with this

```
"firstName":"Juraj","lastName":"
                                arnogurský"}}
```

which ruins the JSON format.

I am using NodeJS btw.

How to encode my last name to the form suitable for network transfer?

**EDIT**

I do this:

```
const jsonrpc = require('jsonrpc-lite');
const requestHttp = require('request');
```

and this:

```
let obj = jsonrpc.request(id, method, params);

requestHttp({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3001/api?data=' + JSON.stringify(obj),
    method: 'GET',
}, (error, response, body) => { ...
```

and as id I send `'1'` as method I send `addCustomer` and as params I send this:

```
{
     customerId: senderID,
     facebookId: senderID,
     firstName: context.user.firstName,
     lastName: context.user.lastName,
}
```

where `context.user.lastName` is Čarnogurský

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Please post more code and give us more context. What direction does the name travel in? How is it sent? How is it encoded?

Comment: @minseong I've edited the question.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent('Č'); //"%C4%8C"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already realised that

```
uri: 'http://localhost:3001/api?data=' + JSON.stringify(obj)
```

had to be replaced with

```
uri: 'http://localhost:3001/api?',
qs: {
  data: JSON.stringify(obj),
}
```

---

This is because all URLs can [only use ASCII](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> URLs are written only with the graphic printable characters of the
>   US-ASCII coded character set.

Your name contains characters outside of the ASCII set.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work by doing this:

```
requestHttp({
        uri: 'http://localhost:3001/api?',
        qs: {
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        },
        method: 'GET',
}, (error, response, body) => { ...
```

instead of this:

```
requestHttp({
     uri: 'http://localhost:3001/api?data=' + JSON.stringify(obj),
     method: 'GET',
}, (error, response, body) => { ...
```